# Java command-line property names must always start with lower case?

Tags: java, prolog

Is there a way to make `java -DFOOBAR=foobar` work? The property value cannot be retrieved. No problem if I do instead `java -Dfoobar=foobar`. Do Java command-line property names must always start with lower case? Unable to find so far a definitive answer or a workaround to have property names in upper case.

I'm using a Bash shell to invoke java from the command-line:

```
$ java -DFOOBAR=foobar -Dfoobar=foobar
```

I'm accessing the property values from a Java implementation of Prolog (JIProlog):

```
JIP:-invoke('java.lang.System', getProperty('java.lang.String'), ['foobar'], Value).
Yes
Value = foobar

JIP:-invoke('java.lang.System', getProperty('java.lang.String'), ['FOOBAR'], Value).
Yes
Value = []
```

P.S. It's indeed a JIProlog bug. Using another Java implementation of Prolog (Lean Prolog), there is no problem in accessing both `FOOBAR` and `foobar` properties:

```
main ?- call_java_class_method('java.lang.System', getProperty(foobar), Result).
Result = foobar

No (more) answers.

main ?- call_java_class_method('java.lang.System', getProperty('FOOBAR'), Result).
Result = FOOBAR

No (more) answers.
```

Comment: How are you checking for the value of foobar?

Comment: Using System getProperty method.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. `System.out.println(System.getProperty("FOOBAR"));` prints `foobar` for me. Note that the `"D"` is not part of the property name.

Comment: As I described in my question, there's no issue when the property name is in lower case (`foobar`).

Comment: It might sound trivial, but if you change the property name to upper-cased, you have to change it both in the command line argument and in your Java program where you query it. Property names are case-sensitive.

Comment: @PauloMoura provide the code that you are using to test this, many pairs of eyes are better one

Comment: I do know that property names are case-sensitive. I do know that the `D`is not part of the property name. This is not a case of trivial typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no case limitation for String.getProperties and -D on the command line.

Give the following runes a go, it will help you to identify where you are going wrong.  The most likely explanation is that a) there is a typo when you are invoking from the command line, 2) or there is a typo in the code.

The following code will print out every property and its value that was detected, along as the FOOBAR/foobar check.

```
    System.out.println( "FOOBAR="+System.getProperty("FOOBAR"));
    System.out.println( "foobar="+System.getProperty("foobar"));

    System.getProperties().list(System.out);
```

When you run this code, notice that most property names are lower case.

Comment: Not my code (see my edited question). From your answer, it look like a bug in JIProlog built-in predicate that gives access to the Java API.

Comment: @PauloMoura Very possibly.  It will also be worth checking the harness that is being used to invoke the command or to start prolog.  At least we have been able to help you rule out the basics.  From here I would dump the properties table as above at each point of hand over and see if the properties are being past along as you expect.  I'll let somebody with more JIProlog experience help you from here.

Comment: I'm not the author of JIProlog but it become open source recently. I may be able to get JIProlog sources and try to locate the bug following your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with Java per se. I believe that the command line parser in the shell you are using is responsible. Have you tried java -D"FOOBAR"=foobar?

Answer (score -1):

Under normal circumstances. Java properties of the variable names are lowercase letter, such as: userName, ShowMessage, but there are special circumstances, taking into account certain interesting English acronym (USA, XML, etc.), JavaBean also allows capital letters beginning the attributes variable name, but must meet the first two letters of the variable is either all uppercase or all lowercase "requirements, such as: the IDCODE ICcard IDCODE property variable name is legal, but the iC, iCcard, iDCode attribute variables The name is illegal.